# undo / go back in history with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a customizations website completely on jQuery (I'm completely new to coding and because that's the only coding I know as of now). Here is the link to the project I'm working on for a friend [here is the link to it](http://hybridimaginations.com/lambada/test.html). I want to get the undo button that's on the top right corner to work.

The user clicks on color, then clicks on the bag part and that areas color changes. The undo button should undo the current color applied and return to the previous color step by step.

I'm also stuck at creating a summary for the colors present on the bag part it just shows all the colors I have selected rather than the colors that's present on the bag.

It would be a great help if some one could help me out with this 2 things. I have been researching an developing this for the past 3 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you are not changing the url you cannot use the browsers go back or history functionality. What I suggest is keep an array the has all of the possible values in an object. That way if you want to go back you can do something like `arr.length-1` to get the previous set of settings.

Comment: Thank you soo much! for the help. now iv learned to create a history with an array. After hunting for a long time online for solutions, im not able to retrieve out the last item from array. how do i do this?  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gXsRx/1/)

Comment: With jQuery you can just do `$([1,2,4,5,7]).last();`

Comment: here is what i have done [click here](http://hybridimaginations.com/lambada/test.html). But the problem is since it goes step by step backwards it has to wait till the item where the previous color was applied in the same part. Is there a way i can split something like this [chick here](http://jsfiddle.net/LdV4s/) will this idea work out?